# How do I solve this $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} (n/\pi) \cos (2\pi/3n) \sin (4\pi/3n) $?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to find its value

$$\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}\pi \cos \left( \frac{2\pi}{3n}\right) \sin \left( \frac{4\pi}{3n}\right)$$

Can you please give just clues for solving it?

Comment: Do you mean $\cos\!\left(\frac{2\pi}{3n}\right)$ and $\sin\!\left(\frac{4\pi}{3n}\right)$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas yes

Comment: A hint would be the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin x)/x$.

Comment: More hints: $\dfrac{\sin({1 \over n})}{{1 \over n}}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**$1^{\rm \large st}$ clue:** What happens to the cosine term as $n\to\infty$?

**$2^{\rm \large nd}$ clue:** Can you relate the rest of it to $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ and, if so, do you know how to do that one?

Comment: The cos term becomes one and how do I make the limit to go to zero instead of infinity ?

Comment: 3rd clue: replace $n$ with $1/x$.

Comment: yay thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{n}{\pi}\sin \frac{4\pi}{3n}=\frac{4}{3}\,\,\frac{\sin\frac{4\pi}{3n}}{\frac{4\pi}{3n}}$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\pi} \cos \frac{2\pi}{3n}\sin \frac{4\pi}{3n}&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4}{3} \cos \frac{2\pi}{3n}\frac{\sin \frac{4\pi}{3n}}{\frac{4\pi}{3n}}\\
                                                                      &= \frac{4}{3}.(\because \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin \frac{4\pi}{3n}}{\frac{4\pi}{3n}}=1\ \text{and} \lim_{n\to\infty}\cos \frac{2\pi}{3n}=\cos 0=1)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Does this count as giving "just clues"?